# How to destructure the array shown below in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I am working in reactjs I'm confused about the array given below. I need to show the value like this `Drinks>Spirits` and `Drinks>Spirits>Gin` from the given array. Can anyone suggest a method to solve this

```
14: {category_id: "17", name: "Pasta", parent_id: "1", status: "1",…}
15: {category_id: "18", name: "Turkish Breakfast", parent_id: "1", status: "1",…}
16: {category_id: "19", name: "Drinks", parent_id: "1", status: "1",…}
categories: [{category_id: "20", name: "Cocktails", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…},…]
0: {category_id: "20", name: "Cocktails", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…}
1: {category_id: "21", name: "Mocktails", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…}
2: {category_id: "22", name: "Beers", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…}
3: {category_id: "23", name: "Hot Drinks", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…}
4: {category_id: "24", name: "Soft Drinks", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…}
5: {category_id: "25", name: "White Wines", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…}
6: {category_id: "26", name: "Red Wines", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…}
7: {category_id: "27", name: "Spirits", parent_id: "19", status: "1", products: [],…}
categories: [{category_id: "30", name: "Gin", parent_id: "27", status: "1",…},…]
0: {category_id: "30", name: "Gin", parent_id: "27", status: "1",…}
categories: []
category_id: "30"
name: "Gin"
parent_id: "27"
products: [{product_id: "214", name: "Gordon’s", status: "1"},…]
status: "1"
1: {category_id: "31", name: "Rum", parent_id: "27", status: "1",…}
2: {category_id: "32", name: "Whisky", parent_id: "27", status: "1",…}
3: {category_id: "33", name: "Brandy", parent_id: "27", status: "1",…}
4: {category_id: "34", name: "Tequila", parent_id: "27", status: "1",…}
5: {category_id: "35", name: "Vodka", parent_id: "27", status: "1",…}
6: {category_id: "36", name: "Liqueurs", parent_id: "27", status: "1",…}
category_id: "27"
name: "Spirits"
parent_id: "19"
products: []
status: "1"
8: {category_id: "28", name: "Rose Wines", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…}
9: {category_id: "29", name: "Champagnes & Sparkling", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…}
10: {category_id: "38", name: "Raki", parent_id: "19", status: "1",…}
category_id: "19"
name: "Drinks"
parent_id: "1"
products: [{product_id: "224", name: "Bell’s", status: "1"}]
status: "1"
17: {category_id: "87", name: "Juice", parent_id: "1", status: "1", products: [], categories: []}
18: {category_id: "90", name: "Category Testing 50", parent_id: "1", status: "1", products: [],…}
```

and Sample tree structure of the above array

[image: Tree structure array screenshot]

Sample UI screenshot
[image: Sample UI of the Result]

Answer (score 1):

How about (check this I did not test it):

```
const getNames = (drinks) => drinks.map(drink => {
  let hasCategoriers = null
  if (drink.categories){
      hasCategoriers = getNames(drink.categories)
    }
    return {
    drink: drink.name,
    categories: hasCategoriers ? hasCategoriers : null
    }
```

Comment: The above is just an example of the array . Loop through the array and show the value of categories name show in the order of parent to child (ie, Drinks is parent and child is Spirit etc) and See sample UI above